# Naming convention for template classes

Tags: c++, templates, naming-conventions, default-parameters

I have a template class of the form:

```
template< typename AType = DefaultAType,
          typename BType = DefaultBType,
          typename CType = DefaultCType >
class MyClass
{ };
```

For most use cases, the defaulted types are perfectly fine. The problem is: in my code I want to refer to `MyClass` and not to `MyClass<>`, since I kinda want to hide the fact that is a templated class for the general use case.

For this reason I want to write:

```
using MyClass = _MyClass<>; // I am still using C++11 and the name needs to be different
```

Now this is just an example, I do not want to use the underscore as a prefix, I would like to find a nice naming convention to identify this type of classes, much like interfaces all starts with `I`, and all abstract classes starts with `Abstract`.

Which could be a good recognizable name for this type of template classes?

Comment: Your current name (underscore followed by capital letter) is undefined behavior, as the standard library is allowed to use those names (and define then)

Comment: You may find better advice on a different StackExchange site. StackOverflow is usually for debugging help and not best practices.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are users supposed to see/use the `MyClass` template? And do you want a name for the alias of `MyClass<>` or for the `MyClass` template? In any case, what constitutes a good name really depends on how it is used and how the defaulted case differs from the non-defaulted ones.

Comment: @JVApen that is why I specified it was just an example

Comment: @AndyG can you suggest one?

Comment: @MaxLanghof for the `_MyClass<>`, so for the "real" class, not the alias

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @AndyG https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/398892/naming-convention-for-template-classes

Comment: @AndyG maybe is a more appropriate site, but community wise doesn't seem any nicer since the question already got -1